# ImportError: cannot import name 'makedirs'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, sklearn-pandas

I tried to import data (as shown below) in Google Colab

```
from imblearn.datasets import make_imbalance
```

But the output I got is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/six.py:31: FutureWarning: The module is deprecated in version 0.21 and will be removed in version 0.23 since we've dropped support for Python 2.7. Please rely on the official version of six (https://pypi.org/project/six/).
  "(https://pypi.org/project/six/).", FutureWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.neighbors.base module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.neighbors. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.neighbors is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.datasets.base module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.datasets. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.datasets is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5e38d91da46a> in <module>()
----> 1 from imblearn.datasets import make_imbalance

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imblearn/datasets/_zenodo.py in <module>()
     58 from sklearn.datasets import get_data_home
     59 from sklearn.datasets.base import Bunch
---> 60 from sklearn.utils.fixes import makedirs
     61 from sklearn.externals import six
     62 from sklearn.utils import check_random_state

ImportError: cannot import name 'makedirs'
```

I have tried googling about this issue for 30 minutes but I haven't made any progress.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: it's been removed for awhile now. see [scikit-learn github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13388)

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the info. Is there any alternative?

Comment: The issues [has been fixed in sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/574). Try to update all your packages first.

Comment: @piratefache I am using sklearn.__version__ = '0.22.1' but still got error

Comment: how about imbalanced-learn? it is the version 0.6.1?

Comment: @piratefache I dont know before this. But after I did ```pip install -U imbalanced-learn``` It is the version 0.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the fix. Just do this:

```
pip install -U imbalanced-learn
```

Everything will works fine.